# Ionic suddenly closes the emulator and the application does not run

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, adb

When I run the code

```
ionic cordova run android,
```

this message is displayed and the emulator opens, but closes suddenly and the application does not run.

how to solve?

when running the command

```
adb devices.
```

the list is empty.

```
 Generating initial manifest for Ionic Deploy...
Ionic Deploy initial manifest successfully generated.
The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Error
> native-run.cmd android --app platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
[native-run] No hardware devices found, attempting emulator...
```